# Embedded question

Tags: embedded-clauses

I was listening to a podcast and I hear a part where I think they should've used an embedded question structure, but I'm not sure because I've been struggling with that grammar.

The statement is:
“Let's focus today on what is it that is causing you anxiety”.
I think it should be: Let's focus today on what it is that is causing you anxiety.

Please help me clarify this.

Answer (score 2):

I agree: *what it is* would be the normal way to phrase it.

But their script might say *Let us focus today on "What is it that is causing you anxiety?"* with a quoted, rather than embedded question. It would be normal to precede the quotation with something like "the question", but not obligatory.

Comment: Yep, this is possible, especially if there was even a slight pause before "what".